# When using the linear_kernel or the cosine_similarity for TfIdfVectorizer I get the error "Kernel died, restarting"

Tags: kernel, cosine-similarity, tfidfvectorizer

When using the linear_kernel or the `cosine_similarity` for `TfIdfVectorizer`, I get the error *"Kernel died, restarting"*.

I am running the scikit learn functions for TfID method Vectorizer and `fit_transform` on some text data like the example below, but when I want to calculate the distance matrix, I get the error *"Kernel died, restarting"*.

Whether I use the the `cosine_similarity` or the `linear_kernel` function:

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word' stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(products['ProductDescription'])

 --cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
 --cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

Maybe the problem is the size of my data?

My tiidf matrix is (178350,143529) which should generate a (178350,178350) cosine_sim matrix.

Comment: If you're trying to find cosine similarity, then why not just do `tfidf_matrix * tfifdf_matrix.T`

Answer (score 0):

As per as I understood, you want to calculate N x N similarity table.

In that case (csr matrix is quite large), it is hard to calculate at once,
My approach was `cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[index], tfidf_matrix[:]) * N times`.

Actually I performed it with pyspark

```
def calculate_one_to_all_similarity(index):
    ...
    cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[index], tfidf_matrix[:]
rdd.map(lambda r: calculate_one_to_all_similarity(r2index[r]))
```